# Ubuntu 17.10 Upgrade: Built-in Audio Lost

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, soundcard, hda-intel

Greeting, saviors. Newbie to this forum here. After a fairly long Google search and troubleshooting, I have to declare defeat on this one. Please feel free to request any info needed to resolve this issue.

My problem is lost audio input/output on my laptop after upgrade (14.04 -> 17.10). I managed to get input (built-in microphone) back, but not the output (built-in speaker).

Here are a list of symptoms:

Symptom #1: **Pulse Audio Control shows unplugged**

[image]

In fact, **Analog Stereo Output** is also unplugged, but not **Analog Stereo Input**.

Symptom #2: **sink index idle**

Issuing `pactl list short | grep analog-stereo` on terminal returns (I manually line break for readibility)

```
1   alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1f.3.analog-stereo  module-alsa-card.c
    s16le 2ch 44100Hz   IDLE
2   alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1f.3.analog-stereo.monitor  module-alsa-card.c  
    s16le 2ch 44100Hz   RUNNING
3   alsa_input.pci-0000_00_1f.3.analog-stereo   module-alsa-card.c
    s16le 2ch 44100Hz   RUNNING
```

Input is running, but output is idle, for unknown reason.

Symptom #3: **Port seems to be NOT AVAILABLE**

I went into the long output of `pactl list`, and found the sound card. In the `profile` section of the sound card description, all profiles shows `available : no`. And the `port` section gives `B-analog-output-lineout: Line Out` and `Not Available`, affecting `output:analog-stereo` and  `output:analog-stereo+input:analog-stereo`. The latter one is probably the duplex setting I want.

```
Card #1
    Name: alsa_card.pci-0000_00_1f.3
    Driver: module-alsa-card.c
    Owner Module: 7
    Properties:
        alsa.card = "0"
        alsa.card_name = "HDA Intel PCH"
        alsa.long_card_name = "HDA Intel PCH at 0xda148000 irq 136"
        alsa.driver_name = "snd_hda_intel"
        device.bus_path = "pci-0000:00:1f.3"
        sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0"
        device.bus = "pci"
        device.vendor.id = "8086"
        device.vendor.name = "Intel Corporation"
        device.product.id = "a170"
        device.product.name = "Sunrise Point-H HD Audio"
        device.form_factor = "internal"
        device.string = "0"
        device.description = "Built-in Audio"
        module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
        device.icon_name = "audio-card-pci"
    Profiles:
        input:analog-stereo: Analog Stereo Input (sinks: 0, sources: 1, priority: 60, available: no)
        output:analog-stereo: Analog Stereo Output (sinks: 1, sources: 0, priority: 6000, available: no)
        output:analog-stereo+input:analog-stereo: Analog Stereo Duplex (sinks: 1, sources: 1, priority: 6060, available: no)
        off: Off (sinks: 0, sources: 0, priority: 0, available: yes)
    Active Profile: output:analog-stereo+input:analog-stereo
    Ports:
        B-analog-output-lineout: Line Out (priority: 9900, latency offset: 0 usec, not available)
            Part of profile(s): output:analog-stereo, output:analog-stereo+input:analog-stereo
```

---

Here I will conclude with some basic info on my system:

```
~$ sudo aplay -l
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: ALC3235 Analog [ALC3235 Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

---

```
~$ sudo alsactl --version
alsactl version 1.1.3
```

---

```
~$ lspci | grep -i audio
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H HD Audio (rev 31)
01:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation Device 0fbc (rev a1)
```

---

Part of the output of `lspci -v` that concerns audio:

```
01:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation Device 0fbc (rev a1)
    Subsystem: Dell Device 16d9
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 17
    Memory at dc080000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: [60] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [68] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [78] Express Endpoint, MSI 00
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H HD Audio (rev 31)
    Subsystem: Dell Sunrise Point-H HD Audio
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 32, IRQ 136
    Memory at da148000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Memory at da120000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=64K]
    Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [60] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel
```

Comment: This solved my problem easily https://askubuntu.com/a/1284429/395192 (for anybody facing the same issue on ubuntu/kubuntu)

Answer (score 1):

I've got a similar problem (but in my case pulseaudio did not start at all). After going through couple of troubleshooters I've decided to purge pulseaudio and install it again.

I know it i like going with a chainsaw to cut a grass, but it worked for me.

Comment: Sorry, didn't work.

Comment: Neither did it for me. See my answer

Answer (score 1):

I followed the advice mentioned in  [this bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/pulseaudio/+bug/1728587) :

> In **/etc/pulse/default.pa:**
>
> Comment out the following line
>
> **load-module module-switch-on-context**
>
> and run
> **sudo alsa force-reload**

It helped.
Kubuntu 17.10 upgraded from 17.04, Intel audio built-in, ASUS Netbook F200M

Comment: The link lead to a "This page does not exist, or you may not have permission to see it. " error. Could you check that the link is correct?

Comment: @J.Starnes thanks, the link is updated, pls. check if it works for you