# Default audio device (typically built-in analog) does not show in Kubuntu 20.10

Tags: sound, kubuntu, pulseaudio, alsa

After updating to Kubuntu 20.10 my built-in analog audio stopped showing in the KDE sound settings. Instead only the built-in digital output was showing.

The device is found by the kernel; `sudo dmesg | grep audio` finds a Realtek ALC887-VD.

The device is found by Alsa; `aplay -L | grep -A2 sysdefault` returns `HDA Intel PCH, ALC887-VD Analog` as default audio device.

The device is found by PulseAudio; `pacmd list-cards | grep analog-output` founds one line out and one headphone jack.

Still in the KDE audio settings I cannot select the analog line out.

Comment: Today Kubuntu 20.10 is released. I tried to install pipewire again and the sound work fine, no issue. So maybe it was fixed with the release. Or maybe it was fixed by removing the package and installing it again.

Comment: Voting to "leave closed".  The original reason for closure has been resolved but I would also vote to close because the solution in comments from the OP suggests that it describes a problem that can't be reproduced, that seemingly went away on its own or was only relevant to a very specific period of time. It's off-topic as it's unlikely to help future readers.

Comment: [What about this bug report for Debian](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=918522) and [this recent comment from an user of Kubuntu 20.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1284262/default-audio-device-typically-built-in-analog-does-not-show-in-kubuntu-20-10?noredirect=1#comment2204952_1284429)? How do you come to the conclusion that the problem went away by itself or was only relevant to a very specific period of time? In at least two cases it only went away after deactivating/uninstalling PipeWire.

Comment: Your comment from Oct 23 states that the problem went away on its own.  Bug reports are off topic here always. This is not where they are triaged and worked on - so it is counterproductive:  File a bug report using the link in the closure note so it goes to the folks who can investigate and fix it.

Comment: I never stated that the problem went away by itself. I did not come here to file a bug but to find a solution for a problem I faced; it was closed because at the time the software was not yet officially released. A bug is already filed [here](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=918522).

Comment: Hi again, is it possible to correct the wrong statement that this issue affects a development version of Kubuntu? This was confirmed by @unloco. And sorry I will not be able to report this as a bug since it is not reproducible nor can I provide any useful information like logs for it. And generally speaking I would expect Ask Ubuntu to be a place where users can help each other by sharing solutions for issues they faced with Ubuntu. Is my understanding wrong? Why are users being punished for sharing findings they had with others?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have no idea why pipewire is included in KDE editions. It's exceedingly buggy and should never have found its way into production systems. You got lucky with `sudo apt-get autoremove --purge pipewire*` because when I do it on an Ubuntu-based KDE, it takes the entire desktop with it.

The better way to deal with pipewire is to disable it in `systemd` then pin it in `apt`.

```
sudo systemctl --global disable pipewire
sudo apt-mark hold libpipewire* pipewire*
```

That disables pipewire and prevents it from getting updated, which could potentially re-enable it.

If you want to control the default audio device, I recommend `pavucontrol`.

```
sudo apt install pavucontrol
```

It will allow you to specify the default output devices and control all audio inputs and outputs.

Comment: Possibly PipeWire is being recommended by mistake by some other package... Kubuntu 20.10 will be released next week, maybe PipeWire will be removed from the upgrade. Thanks for the hint regarding dependencies.

Comment: Another question: will apt-mark work with all package managers? I usually prefer dpkg-hold.

Comment: @StéphaneTréboux I faced the same issue on Kubuntu 20.10

Comment: Hello @unloco, I am happy to read that you found this solution. If you think that this hint was helpful and the issue you faced was after Kubuntu 20.10 was officially released then you can vote to reopen this question. At the moment this question is closed because I found the issue before the official release of Kubuntu and hence the question was considered off-topic.

Comment: @StéphaneTréboux The commands on the answer above fixed the issue for me. Now my analog audio works perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

After running `fuser -v /dev/snd/*` the culprit appears; [PipeWire](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PipeWire) is using the default audio device. Since I don't use PipeWire I did not even try to reconfigure it and I removed it with `sudo apt-get autoremove --purge pipewire*`; be careful to only remove the five or so packages directly related to PipeWire. After a computer restart the audio device was showing again in the KDE sound settings.

[The same issues was found with Timidity in Debian.](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=918522) In both cases the issue seems to be linked to NVIDIA GPUs.