# How to enable Starship/Matisse HD Audio Controller?

Tags: sound

I have two sound output options on my Ubuntu 20.10 machine.

One is the HDMI audio that runs to my monitor's headphone jack.

The other is the built-in HD audio on my motherboard.

I can't seem to enable the one on my motherboard.  The only profile option in the audio settings is "off".

[image]

Here is my lspci output:

```
$ lspci -k | grep -A 4 Audio
28:00.4 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse HD Audio Controller
        Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] Starship/Matisse HD Audio Controller
        Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
        Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel
```

and lshw:

```
$ sudo lshw -class multimedia
  *-multimedia              
       description: Audio device
       product: TU116 High Definition Audio Controller
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0.1
       bus info: pci@0000:26:00.1
       version: a1
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
       configuration: driver=snd_hda_intel latency=0
       resources: irq:64 memory:fc080000-fc083fff
  *-multimedia
       description: Audio device
       product: Starship/Matisse HD Audio Controller
       vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
       physical id: 0.4
       bus info: pci@0000:28:00.4
       version: 00
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm pciexpress msi bus_master cap_list
       configuration: driver=snd_hda_intel latency=0
       resources: irq:66 memory:fc400000-fc407fff
```

not sure what other info I should provide.  The sound thru my HDMI output works fine, but I'd like to be able to use the other one also.

Comment: Maybe your mainboard built-in sound card is taken by Pipewire? See https://askubuntu.com/questions/1284262/default-audio-device-typically-built-in-analog-does-not-show-in-kubuntu-20-10

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Enable Starship/Matisse HD Audio Controller?

Here’s what I did:

1. run `pavucontrol`
2. under the Configuration tab (all the way to the right - it might not be visible initially), disable any audio devices you don’t intend to use
3. under the “Output Devices” tab, select “Port: Headphones (unplugged)”
4. To make the change permanent, edit the `default.pa` file with elevated privileges:

   ```
   sudo {text editor of choice} /etc/pulse/default.pa`
   ```

   <sup>**Note:** Be sure to replace `{text editor of choice}` with your {text editor of choice}.</sup>

   Add the following to the end of the file:

   ```
   set-sink-port 0 analog-output-headphones
   ```

To list all of the details of your sound devices, you can run `pactl list cards`. When referencing the device number in `/etc/pulse/default.pa`, be sure to use the value under `alsa.card` and NOT the initial `Card #` listing. In my case `Card#0` was `alsa.card = "1"` and vice versa.

[Source](https://forum.level1techs.com/t/has-anybody-gotten-audio-working-in-linux-on-aorus-x570-master/154072/14)

Comment: You saved my day!